# Is there a way to dynamically add a specific class for domain and subdomain in Drupal? Using tokens

Tags: php, css, drupal, drupal-7

I want to set a Domain-specific css class and a subdomain-specific css class. I don't want to use a script that sees if the url is a domain or subdomain, I want to use a token in Domain settings in Drupal 7.

Is there any way to do this? Are some tokens that allow a class to be added only on domains and only on subdomains? Or a way to define my own tokens for example so they know what to do?

Existing token example: [current-domain:id]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should use domain token module. It's not a final version but maybe you may find it useful.

https://drupal.org/project/domain_token

Regards.

Comment: I'm not sure if this gives me conditional tokens according to the domain or subdomain

Comment: Yup, and still couldn't find something that suited me

Comment: You can create your custom tokens. Read this article please: https://drupal.org/taxonomy/term/32498

Comment: Ok, I managed to create a custom token, but I can't find where to write to be able to differentiate domains from subdomains. When creating a token, there is a content area, that is not compilable unfortunately. Is there another way to define what string to return?